# How can I can highlight words that are more or equal to 8 characters in paragraph? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, highlight

I am trying to highlight the words that are equal or greater than 8 characters from the paragraph. I tried to put some code from other sources but it doesn't work. Here is the code:

```
enter code here
let txt=document.createElement("p").innerText;

 function highlightWords() {
     let words = txt.split(" ");
     let size = 8
     for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
         let word = words[i];
         let processedP = "<p>";
         if (index>=8) {
             innerText=innerText.substring(0,index)+ "<span class='lightext'>"+innerText.substring(index,index+txt.length)+ "</span>" + innerText.substring(index + txt.length);
         } else {
         }

         return txt;

     }
 }

 highlightWords();
```

[JsBin](https://jsbin.com/rukupojifo/edit?html,css,js,output) my web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had many of the right pieces there, just needed to put them together a bit differently.

I have put together a complete HTML that has it all working together, with some comments on how things are working.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .lightext {
            background-color: yellow;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="targetp">This is the extremely long paragraph that we want to highlight all words longer than eight characters in.</p>
<script>


function highlightWords() {
    const txt = document.getElementById("targetp").innerText;
    let output = "";
    let words = txt.split(" ");
    let size = 8   //don't really need this - size as a variable isn't used anywhere else,
    let replacementword = ""; //this will store our output - it's easier than trying to update thee text "in place"
    for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        let word = words[i];
        if (word.length >= 8) {  //this is where we figure out if the word is longer than 8
            replacementword = "<span class='lightext'>" + word + "</span>";  //if it is, we just need to wrap it in a span with lighttext class - assuming you have a "highlighted" style applied to class lightext, see styles above for mine
        } 
        else {
            replacementword = word;  //shorter than 8, don't need to change anything
        }
        output = output + " " + replacementword + " ";  //add the updated word to our output
    }

    return output; //return our finished output string to the function call
}

document.getElementById("targetp").innerHTML = highlightWords();   //actually update the <p> tag with the new text, WHICH is now HTML rather than just plain text
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @fliptopbox points out a flaw in my original code - I had output and txt defined globally rather than locally.  They are spot on that this is bad practice; scope variables only as broadly as they need.  I have corrected the code.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution.

```js
const p = document.getElementById('p');

const splitWords = p.innerHTML.split(' ');
const highlightedWords = splitWords.map((word) =>
  word.length >= 8 ? `<span class="highlight">${word}</span>` : word
);
const joinedWords = highlightedWords.join(' ');

p.innerHTML = joinedWords;
```

```css
.highlight {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Parapgraph Highlight</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>


  <p id="p">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis porro praesentium quas quisquam recusandae? At cum dignissimos dolorem est eveniet id ipsum nesciunt optio, porro quasi quis sequi sunt suscipit.</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, your JSBIin is not working, so you might want to fix that before you post, the problem is the `let txt=document.createElement("p").innerText;` There you are creating the Element, where in fact you should be reading it, with `querySelector`

Here is just one of many ways to achieve the result.

```js
function highlightLongWords(txt, max = 8) {
  return txt.split(/(\s+)/g)
    .map(word => word.length >= max ? `<em>${word}</em>` : word)
    .join(" ");
}

// get your get from the DOM element
const p = document.querySelector("#p").innerText;

console.log(highlightLongWords(p)); // greater than or equal 8 characters
console.log(highlightLongWords(p, 12)); // greater than or equal 12 characters
```

Here is the explanation:

1. Split the text (as you did) but ...

- Using a Regular Expression `\s` is a space
- `/\s+/` means one or more spaces

2. Use `map` to loop over every word
3. Use ternary expression to check the word length:

- if it is >= 8, use string template to change the word and wrap it with `em`
- otherwise keep the original value of the word

4. Join the array of words into a paragraph

Lastly notice that this function has a 2nd argument that allows you to use it more broadly, and it does not use global variables which means you can put this code anywhere and it will work with the arguments you provide. Try not to use global variables :D